# On a wire designated as '3x14AWG' what does the '3x' part mean?

Tags: wire, surge-protection, gauge, awg

On a wire designated as '3x14AWG' what does the '3x' part mean?

It is on a wire that is part of a surge protector power strip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'3x' = 3 of.

It is specifying a 3-core cable with 14 AWG conductors. These will be L, N and E or live, neutral and earth.

Comment: Regarding "3 of" - I'll just add that a (perhaps old-fashioned?) approach would be to say "off" instead of "of". e.g. "3 off" (or 1 off, 2 off etc.). See [this example parts list](http://tvrrug.org.uk/electronics-v1-2-parts) and [this discussion](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english/electronics-elect-eng/1417774-1-off-2-off-3-off.html).

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for the comment. I'm familiar with that usage as it is standard practice in Britain (the largest island off the coast of Ireland, where I live). I've never been comfortable with it though as it sounded odd. I've just done a web search which brought me to [English StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385024/use-of-the-word-off-to-indicate-a-quantity) which confirms my bias!

Comment: @Transistor That's the best geographical description I've heard in a long time :)